# NSSet(array: myArray) works on OS X but crashes in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, swift, macos, foundation, nsset

The following code works in a Playground on OS X but doesn't work once compiled in Ubuntu using Swift.org.

---

#### In a Playground

This works as expected:

```
let permutedHands = [["A♦", "A♣", "6♠", "3♦", "T♥"], ["A♣", "A♦", "6♠", "3♦", "T♥"], ["6♠", "A♦", "A♣", "3♦", "T♥"], ["A♦", "6♠", "A♣", "3♦", "T♥"], ["T♥", "6♠", "A♦", "3♦", "A♣"], ["6♠", "T♥", "A♦", "3♦", "A♣"], ["A♦", "T♥", "6♠", "3♦", "A♣"], ["T♥", "A♦", "6♠", "3♦", "A♣"], ["6♠", "A♦", "T♥", "3♦", "A♣"], ["A♦", "6♠", "T♥", "3♦", "A♣"], ["3♦", "6♠", "A♦", "T♥", "A♣"], ["6♠", "3♦", "A♦", "T♥", "A♣"], ["A♦", "3♦", "6♠", "T♥", "A♣"], ["3♦", "A♦", "6♠", "T♥", "A♣"], ["6♠", "A♦", "3♦", "T♥", "A♣"], ["A♦", "6♠", "3♦", "T♥", "A♣"], ["3♦", "T♥", "A♦", "6♠", "A♣"], ["T♥", "3♦", "A♦", "6♠", "A♣"], ["A♦", "3♦", "T♥", "6♠", "A♣"], ["3♦", "A♦", "T♥", "6♠", "A♣"], ["T♥", "A♦", "3♦", "6♠", "A♣"], ["A♦", "T♥", "3♦", "6♠", "A♣"], ["3♦", "T♥", "6♠", "A♦", "A♣"], ["T♥", "3♦", "6♠", "A♦", "A♣"], ["6♠", "3♦", "T♥", "A♦", "A♣"], ["3♦", "6♠", "T♥", "A♦", "A♣"], ["T♥", "6♠", "3♦", "A♦", "A♣"], ["6♠", "T♥", "3♦", "A♦", "A♣"]]

let sortedPerms = permutedHands.map { $0.sort() }
let permSet = NSSet(array: sortedPerms)
let arr = Array(permSet) // [["3♦", "6♠", "A♣", "A♦", "T♥"]]
```

#### With `swift build` for Swift.org in Linux

Error message at compilation:

> cannot convert value of type '[[String]]' to expected argument type '[AnyObject]'
>   let permSetArray = NSSet(array: sortedPerms)

I tried this in desperation, just in case:

```
let sortedPerms = perms.map { $0.sort() }.map { $0 as! AnyObject }
```

It makes the compiler happy but then it crashes at runtime:

> Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Array' (0x7f84701950d8) to 'Swift.AnyObject' (0x7f84701700e8).
>   Aborted (core dumped)

I've skimmed through the Swift GitHub repositories but didn't find anything unimplemented or incomplete about NSSet, it looks ok in Swift.org's Foundation (as far as I can tell).

Any idea how to debug and fix this? A workaround could be also acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try Swift on Linux yet, but you can use this 'pure' Swift solution without `import Foundation`:

```
let permutedHands = [["A♦", "A♣", "6♠", "3♦", "T♥"], ["A♣", "A♦", "6♠", "3♦", "T♥"], ["6♠", "A♦", "A♣", "3♦", "T♥"], ["A♦", "6♠", "A♣", "3♦", "T♥"], ["T♥", "6♠", "A♦", "3♦", "A♣"], ["6♠", "T♥", "A♦", "3♦", "A♣"], ["A♦", "T♥", "6♠", "3♦", "A♣"], ["T♥", "A♦", "6♠", "3♦", "A♣"], ["6♠", "A♦", "T♥", "3♦", "A♣"], ["A♦", "6♠", "T♥", "3♦", "A♣"], ["3♦", "6♠", "A♦", "T♥", "A♣"], ["6♠", "3♦", "A♦", "T♥", "A♣"], ["A♦", "3♦", "6♠", "T♥", "A♣"], ["3♦", "A♦", "6♠", "T♥", "A♣"], ["6♠", "A♦", "3♦", "T♥", "A♣"], ["A♦", "6♠", "3♦", "T♥", "A♣"], ["3♦", "T♥", "A♦", "6♠", "A♣"], ["T♥", "3♦", "A♦", "6♠", "A♣"], ["A♦", "3♦", "T♥", "6♠", "A♣"], ["3♦", "A♦", "T♥", "6♠", "A♣"], ["T♥", "A♦", "3♦", "6♠", "A♣"], ["A♦", "T♥", "3♦", "6♠", "A♣"], ["3♦", "T♥", "6♠", "A♦", "A♣"], ["T♥", "3♦", "6♠", "A♦", "A♣"], ["6♠", "3♦", "T♥", "A♦", "A♣"], ["3♦", "6♠", "T♥", "A♦", "A♣"], ["T♥", "6♠", "3♦", "A♦", "A♣"], ["6♠", "T♥", "3♦", "A♦", "A♣"]]

let sortedPerms = permutedHands.map { $0.sort() }
var arr: Array<Array<String>> = []
sortedPerms.forEach { (a) -> () in
    let contains = arr.contains{ $0 == a }
    if !contains {
        arr.append(a)
    }
}
print(arr) // [["3♦", "6♠", "A♣", "A♦", "T♥"]]
```

Comment: you welcome. i understand, that you don't need to implement Hashable for NSSet, but the final performance of this 'workaround' should be not worst as using NSSet. it is nice, i can help you